# how to create a dummy REST server API to check my android http request\response?

Tags: java, android, apache, http, rest

I want to send and recieve http REST from and to the android app I'm writing.

I will look for the android code, but how can i simulate it end-to-end?

is there any dummy website I can set a stub server for http REST?

Comment: You could use [apiary.io](http://apiary.io/how-it-works) which also creates a documentation for the REST API. Though, it is still in development so things might work or might not.

Comment: How are you going to implement your backend? PHP, Ruby, Java, Node.js? I think it's not a trivial task to provide a generic stub server where you can achieve meaningful test results.

Answer (score 1):

It is very easy to build one using Java and Spring Boot. Just checkout this project https://github.com/alessiop86/dummy-server

and extend MyRestController accordingly to your test.. adding one method for each request you need to handle (you could also define dynamic methods with parameters, look for `@PathVariable` documentation).

```
@RestController
public class MyRestController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/users/1")
    public @ResponseBody String method1() throws IOException {
        return "<output>1</output>";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/hello/2")
    public @ResponseBody String method2() throws IOException {
        return "{'hi':'alessio'}";
    }
}
```